# Sorting questions?

Tags: sorting, heap

Is a heap sort considered a "divide and conquer" sort or a priority queue sort?

Also, what category of sort would a bubble sort fit into (other than horrible).

I've read that a heap sort is generally considered a "divide and conquer" sort, but it can be a priority queue sort. Is it strictly one or the other? Or is it some how both? I cannot find anything on what a bubble sort may be considered.

Comment: These are two different questions and should be asked as such. Additionally please show some sort of research on your part.

Comment: Ok, I thought they were both grouped into the same category so they could be asked together.

Comment: A bubble sort would be a "naive"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think `HeapSort` is considered "Divide and Conquer", because in no moment the algorithm sub-divides the problem into sub-problems. To do HeapSort the algorithm Executes `ExtractMin` or `ExtractMax` until the Heap is empty. These actions are `O(logn)` because after each `ExtractMin` or `ExtractMax` the `Heap` has to do `Heapify` to mantain the partial-order of it. At the end has a cost of `O(nlogn)` because it does `n` `ExtractMin` or `ExtractMax`.

Here is a pseudo-code

```
HeapSort()
 heap
 new_ ordered_collection
 while(heap.NotEmpty)
   new_ ordered_collection.add(heap.ExtractMin)//or ExtractMax
   heap.Heapify //could be MaxHeapify or MinHeapify
 return new_ ordered_collection
```

Notice that `ExtractMin` and `ExtractMax` pops out the minimum or the maximum element of the Heap.

As you can see, i don't see the "Divide and Conquer" strategy.

But the `heap.Heapify` reorder the elements based on the partial order of the heap. This one defines the relationship between each node and his two child, because of this, `heap.Heapify` applies a "Divide and Conquer" strategy, but that is a thing of the DataStructre itself no of the algorithm.

And bubble sort is a `naive` algorithm.

Comment: Perfect that's what I needed to know!

Comment: It's good to know! I forgot to mention that creating a Heap takes `O(n)` operations. But still `O(nlogn)` the entire algorithm. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: If you were given an unsorted array, how do you build the heap first? Building the heap from an unsorted array can be done in O(n) using a divide-and-conquer algorithm. See here: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960118.html

Answer (score 1):

Heap sort has the time complexity of a 'divide and conquer' algorithm (such as quick sort), but it does not behave like a divide and conquer algorithm.

Because it splits the data into a 'sorted' section and an 'unsorted' section, it is really a kind of selection sort.  It takes advantage of the heap data structure to more efficiently select the minimum element from the unsorted list at each step.  I suppose you could say it is a 'priority queue sort' because of this, but it should be mentioned that the entire operation can be done in-place rather than building a separate heap.

Heap sort is typically outperformed by quicksort, except that quicksort has a worst-case complexity of `O(N^2)` (versus heap sort's worst case of `O(N.logN)`).

Bubble sort is also an in-place algorithm, but it is considered 'naive'.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, heap sort is definitely not a "Divide and Conquer" algorithm. Heap sort uses a heap data structure to efficiently sort its elements. You can think of heap sort as selection sort with a priority queue.

Divide and conquer algorithms have the following characteristics:

1) Partition task into sub-tasks which are smaller instances of the same tasks
2) Recursively solve the sub-tasks
3) Appropriately combine the results

As you can see heap sort does not qualify as this type of algorithm. The only similarity is the structure of a divide and conquer algorithm mirrors that of a binary tree (which is typically what heap sort uses to implement a priority queue).